# How can I specify all verb actions in kubernetes when creating a role?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

Instead of specifying each one of the allowed actions:

```
kubectl create clusterrole storage-admin --verb=create,list,watch,create,get --resource=persistentvolumes --resource=storageclasses
```

I would like to specify that all verbs are allowed:

```
kubectl create clusterrole storage-admin --verb='*' --resource=persistentvolumes --resource=storageclasses
```

It works but is there an easier or better way to do it?

Comment: your command should work, is there any issue?

Comment: it seems correct, https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.19/#clusterrole-v1-rbac-authorization-k8s-io

Comment: `kubectl edit clusterrole cluster-admin` and you can verify, it should allow all verb